# Logcat error while running app in android real devices

Tags: android

I'm trying to run simple app and get the output in the logcat as "helloworld". When I try to run the app in the real device I'm getting error as 
**load_library(linker.cpp:759) :library "libmalinnstr.so not found** and also 6 **isScreenOn --> false**. I tried all the solution which is there in the internet but didn't work.
When I try to run my app in ambrane tab it is working fine with displaying the output in the logcat. When I try to run in karbon titanium I am getting the error.
What would be the solution to this problem. Please help.

Comment: Not knowing the specifics of the devices, my guess would be it sounds like maybe the `libmalinnstr.so` is compiled for one ARM instruction set which exists on the Ambrane tablet, but it isn't compiled for ARMv7 running on the Karbonn Titanium?

Comment: cpu :ARM Cortex-A7 , gpu:Arm Mali-400 MP2 is the specs of karbonn. how do i resolve this problem